# How can I have a custom AppBar for each sub screen when using bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have one main screen with `AppBar` which also has `bottomNavigationBar`.

Since the `AppBar` is set in the main screen's `Scaffold`, I am unable to have custom titles for each subscreen.

As you may see, all sub-screens get the same `AppBar` since it's set at the Main Screen level.

[image: Sub Screen 1]
[image: Sub Screen 2]

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can create a `List<AppBar>` and show with `appbarList[_selectedIndex]`

code snippet

```
List<AppBar> appbarList = [
    AppBar(
      title: const Text('Home'),
    ),
    AppBar(
      title: const Text('Basic AppBar'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        // action button
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        // action button
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.event),
          onPressed: () {},
        ), // overflow menu
      ],
    ),
    AppBar(
      title: const Text('School'),
    ),
  ];
... 
Scaffold(
  appBar: appbarList[_selectedIndex],
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<AppBar> appbarList = [
    AppBar(
      title: const Text('Home'),
    ),
    AppBar(
      title: const Text('Basic AppBar'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        // action button
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        // action button
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.event),
          onPressed: () {},
        ), // overflow menu
      ],
    ),
    AppBar(
      title: const Text('School'),
    ),
  ];

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appbarList[_selectedIndex],
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('School'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```